# Rows with rowspan have bigger height

Tags: html, css, html-table

I'm building this html table:

```
<div class="parser-table-wrapper">
    <table class="parser-table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Category</th>
                <th>Value</th>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Number</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="tbody-filter-market-country-specialty">
            <tr class="parser-row">
                <th rowspan="6">1</th>
                <td class="parser-value-cell table-value-cell">a</td>
                <td class="parser-value-cell table-value-cell">a1</td>
                <td class="parser-value-cell table-value-cell">1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="parser-row">
                <td class="parser-value-cell table-value-cell">b</td>
                <td class="parser-value-cell table-value-cell">b1</td>
                <td class="parser-value-cell table-value-cell">2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="parser-row">
                <td class="parser-value-cell table-value-cell">c</td>
                <td class="parser-value-cell table-value-cell">c1</td>
                <td class="parser-value-cell table-value-cell">3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="parser-row">
                <td class="parser-value-cell table-value-cell">d</td>
                <td class="parser-value-cell table-value-cell">d1</td>
                <td class="parser-value-cell table-value-cell">4</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="parser-row">
                <td class="parser-value-cell table-value-cell">e</td>
                <td class="parser-value-cell table-value-cell">e1</td>
                <td class="parser-value-cell table-value-cell">5</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="parser-row last-value-row">
                <td class="parser-value-cell table-value-cell">f</td>
                <td class="parser-value-cell table-value-cell">f1</td>
                <td class="parser-value-cell table-value-cell">6</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="parser-row">
                <th rowspan="2">2</th>
                <td class="parser-value-cell table-value-cell">a</td>
                <td class="parser-value-cell table-value-cell">a1</td>
                <td class="parser-value-cell table-value-cell">1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="parser-row last-value-row">
                <td class="parser-value-cell table-value-cell">b</td>
                <td class="parser-value-cell table-value-cell">b1</td>
                <td class="parser-value-cell table-value-cell">2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="parser-row">
                <th rowspan="2">3</th>
                <td class="parser-value-cell table-value-cell">a</td>
                <td class="parser-value-cell table-value-cell">a1</td>
                <td class="parser-value-cell table-value-cell">1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="parser-row last-value-row">
                <td class="parser-value-cell table-value-cell">b</td>
                <td class="parser-value-cell table-value-cell">b1</td>
                <td class="parser-value-cell table-value-cell">1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="parser-row">
                <th rowspan="2">4</th>
                <td class="parser-value-cell table-value-cell">a</td>
                <td class="parser-value-cell table-value-cell">a1</td>
                <td class="parser-value-cell table-value-cell">1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="parser-row last-value-row">
                <td class="parser-value-cell table-value-cell">b</td>
                <td class="parser-value-cell table-value-cell">b1</td>
                <td class="parser-value-cell table-value-cell">2</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

with the following css:

```
body {
  font-family: "lato",Arial,sans-serif;
  color: rgba(0,0,0,0.84);
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.4em;
}

.parser-table-wrapper {
     border: 1px solid #9e9e9e;
     border-radius: 2px;
     margin: 18px 10% 12px 10%;
     overflow-x: auto;
}
 .parser-table-wrapper table {
     width: 100%;
     border-radius: 3px;
     box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #9e9e9e;
}
 .parser-table-wrapper table th, .parser-table-wrapper table td {
     border-bottom: 0px;
     font-size: 15px;
     line-height: 1.25;
     min-width: 30px;
     max-width: 120px;
     text-align: left;
}
 .parser-table-wrapper table th {
     padding: 6px;
     background-color: #dcdcdc;
}
 .parser-table-wrapper table td.table-value-cell {
     height: 30.4px;
     padding-left: 6px;
}
 .parser-table-wrapper table tbody tr th {
     background-color: #fff;
     border-bottom: 1px solid #cdcdcd;
}
 .parser-table-wrapper table tbody tr:nth-child(even) td {
     background-color: #efefef;
}
 .parser-table-wrapper table tbody .last-value-row {
     border-bottom: 1px solid #cdcdcd;
}
 .parser-table-wrapper table tfoot {
     background-color: #e2e2e2;
}

table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}

tbody {
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

and I want that all rows to have the same height but it seems the first row of each category (the ones containing a th with a rowspan attribute) add an extra 0.8px, even if I set the height to a specific value. Any ideas how to solve this issue?

here is the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/89x0j6a4/

**Edit**: Seems like adding a border to the tr and the `border-collapse` style to table affects the rows height. Any idea how to add those borders without affecting the row height?

Comment: I'm not seeing which row you mean has extra height.

Comment: The first row of each category

Comment: .parser-table-wrapper table tbody .last-value-row {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #cdcdcd; 
}  --- This border is causing the discrepancies in the row heights.

Comment: @CharleneVas That doesn't seem to be causing the first row to change. When I hover over it with the chrome element selector it shows 33px tall, and the one below it shows 32... Even with that line commented out

Comment: @MichaelMcQuade once that border is commented out - it shows as 32px on both the rows. I'm using the chrome dev tools to inspect the elements.

Comment: Yeah it is that border, and also the border-collapse style. Which adds an extra border to the thead. Any ideas how to add those borders without affecting the row height?